# Как избавить от автоматической установки новой таблицы

Tags: java, mysql

Проблема: создаётся один раз новая таблица когда делаю post запрос через Bash консоль. Остальные запросы идут в новую таблицу.
Чем ему не нравятся те базы данных, которые имеются. Как понимаю - он о них просто не знает, а я не понимаю как его направить в нужную. Хотя все переменные также названы.

**Проблема была найдена, создаётся из-за аннотации Entity в классе Message. Просьба вас подсказать мне как сделать, чтобы добавлялась уже в существующую таблицу. Также не совсем понимаю, что нужно добавить/изменить, чтобы принимали json post запросы.**

Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.api")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

MainController

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller    
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") /
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository TestApi;

    @PostMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
            , @RequestParam String email) {
        Message n = new Message();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        TestApi.save(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Message> getAllUsers() {
        return TestApi.findAll();
    }
}
```

Message

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Integer> {

}
```

application.propirties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Test?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: Пытался через @Table(name = "ApiTable")  в существующую, а он генерирует новую api_table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала можно навести порядок в коде

```
Message --> User

private UserRepository userRepository; // TestApi <-- чтобы никто не догадался?
```

Хибернейт по умолчанию ищет/создает таблицу с именем энтити

```
@Table(name = "USER") // при именовании база данных не различает регистр, но лучше определить какой то один вариант и следовать ему
```

можно один раз запустить приложение с ключем, хмбернейт создаст таблицу

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

потом уже поменять на update